# Averaging dataframe and subplotting with pandas (image included)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Editing to answer a question below:

I'm wondering how to display a scatter/line subplot (containing 8 child plots). I don't know how to parse the dataframe, filter, average the baseball scores for a player for coach 1 for the 1st point on the line/scatter plot, then average coach 2 for the second point... I guess I'm lost on grouping/mean. I can imagine a way to do this with 24 dataframes where I group/mean 1 player on 1 day with a y/x axis of score/coach but that MUST be wrong.

...

Using Pandas (Python 3+), I have a dataframe (imported from a CSV).  It's data from baseball players.  It's broken up into 5 columns with headers- `Day, Player_Score, Bat, Coach, Player`.

`Day = 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'`

`Player_Score = range 0-5` (NOT average but a particular score on a particular day with a particular coach)

`Player = Red, Green, Blue`

`Bat = Bat_A or Bat_B`

`Coach = 1, 2, 3, 4`

I am REALLY struggling to use Pandas / matplotlib / numpy.

I need 8 subplots.  `fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=4)`

y-axis = average **score** for a particular **bat** for a particular **coach** on a particular **day**

Each subplot will be a Bat (A or B) and a Day (Sun-Wed) and their axis is a x='Coach' (1-4), y=average.

average score is NOT in the dataset and must be calculated from half dozen scores.

Any help would be appreciated.

[Baseball Scores Across Players and Days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSnVw.png)

```py
Coach,Player,Day,Score_BatA,Score_BatB
1,Red,Sun,2,2
2,Green,Mon,3,1
3,Blue,Tue,1,3
4,Red,Wed,2,2
1,Green,Wed,4,1
2,Blue,Sun,3,2
3,Red,Mon,3,4
4,Green,Tue,4,2
1,Blue,Wed,4,4
2,Red,Tue,2,5
3,Green,Sun,3,3
4,Blue,Mon,1,3
1,Red,Tue,2,1
2,Green,Wed,4,2
3,Blue,Mon,2,4
4,Red,Sun,3,2
1,Green,Mon,2,4
2,Blue,Tue,3,3
3,Red,Wed,2,3
4,Green,Sun,3,1
1,Blue,Sun,1,2
2,Red,Mon,2,4
3,Green,Tue,4,2
4,Blue,Wed,2,5
```

Comment: Can you provide some data for this question?

Comment: What about making up some sample data this way we can give you a complete verifiable solution?

Comment: Edit: Will do.... Just made one.

Comment: Added to question.  The CSV doesn't format well but I copied and pasted successfully into a CSV.

Comment: What is the actual issue here?

Comment: Hey AMC, how do you display a scatter/line subplot (containing 8  child plots).  I don't know how to parse the dataframe, filter, average the baseball scores for a player for coach 1 for the 1st point on the line/scatter plot, then average coach 2 for the second point...  I guess I'm lost on grouping/mean.  I can imagine a way to do this with 24 dataframes where I group/mean 1 player on 1 day with a y/x axis of score/coach but that MUST be wrong.  Right?